# Can a vertex coexist in both novisited stack and Visited Queue at the same instance in tracing path of Deapth First Search Traversal of a Graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

This is about an algorithm that  is narrated in one of a prescribed text book for undergraduates who has taken datastructure as one of their  subjects.

What i understood from the below algorithm  is that

- First you start from a node push it into notvisited stack
- explore each successor node and push those node to a stack named as
  nonvisited if they are not visited
- poping each node from unvisited stack

Then you recursively follow this procedure  until you finish traversing the graph
fully

My doubt is in this line

**if(vertex is not present on Visited ) Then add vertex on Visited**

My understanding is

- vertex will be present in the Visited queue if it is  already been
  poped out from nonvisited stack and pushed into visited queue
- and vertex will not be present in the Visited queue if it has not
  been pushed into the nonVisited stack

Since we are taking nodes from nonvisited stack to be inserted to the queue why do we need this line

***if(vertex is not present on Visited )  Then add vertex on Visited***

### Wont it it make additional duplication of instructions to the program

as a vertex cannot coexist simultaneosly at the same time in noth notvisited stack and Visited Queue

```
 Algorithm DFS(firstVertex)
{
    add firstVertex on notVisited;
    place NULL on Visited;
    while (notVisited is not empty)
    {
        remove vertex from notVisited;
        generate successors of vertex;

        for each successor of vertex do
        {
            if (successor is not present on Visited and successor is not present on notVisited)
            Then add vertex on front of notVisited;
        }

        if (vertex is not present on Visited)
        Then add vertex on Visited;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that pseudo code your code, or did you see it like that in the course material?

Comment: Is there a reason why it is not indented? Can you include a screenshot of that pseudo code so we can ensure how it looks in your material, or else, can you faithfully reproduce it? It currently has at least two spelling mistakes, is inconsistent in the use of semi-colons, making me doubt about the rest too...

Comment: @trincot thanks for your kindness to look into the doubt ...and your willingness to help...I have added the screenshot of the code from study material

Comment: OK, comparing with the screenshot I see that you have misplaced some closing braces in the text version. The `if` statement you ask about occurs inside the inner loop in the text version, but in the image, it is outside of it. Can you correct, and use indentation like in the image?

Comment: @trincot.  I should have been more carefull ...Extremly grateful to you for pointing that out... hope i have made the correct editing now

Comment: Indentation is important to programmers. Can you apply it?

Comment: @trincot ..thanks for pointing that out ..have done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the condition of the following statement

```
  if (vertex is not present on Visited) Then add vertex on Visited;
```

...is always going to be true. A vertex is not supposed to be in both `notVisited` and `Visited` at the same time, and since we had just removed `vertex` from `notVisited` it cannot be in `Visited` at that time.

There is however a boundary case if the graph could have an edge from a node to itself (a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory))). In that case `vertex` could be a successor of itself. In the first iteration of the loop, such `vertex` is neither in `notVisited`, nor in `Visited`, and is added to the `notVisited` queue **again**. Once the inner loop has finished, `vertex` will be added to `Visited`, so that now it **is** in both collections! This means an extra iteration of the outer loop will be executed for that same `vertex` (luckily not leading to an infinite loop), but then the quoted `if` condition will be **false** for that `vertex`.

The correct way is to move `vertex` **immediately** from `notVisited` to `Visited`, *before* the inner loop starts.

So:

```
Algorithm DFS(firstVertex)
{
    add firstVertex on notVisited;
    place NULL on Visited;
    while (notVisited != NULL)
    {
        remove vertex from notVisited;
        add vertex on Visited;   // <---
        generate successors of vertex;
        for each successor of vertex do
        {
            if (successor is not present on Visited and successor is not present on notVisited)
                Then add vertex on front of notVisited;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can be sure that during the execution of the algorithm, a (reachable) vertex will always go through the following phases, in this order:

1. It is not in `notVisited` nor in `Visited`
2. It is only in `notVisited`
3. It is only in `Visited`

You mention that `notVisited` is a queue, but for efficiency it would be better if it were a [hash set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), such that checking whether a vertex is in that collection has an amortised constant time complexity (not needing to iterate over the whole queue).

For the same reasons, `visited` should not need to be a stack, but can be a hash set as well.